# How to count how many times a word is in the start and in the end?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I want to write a script that will accept 2 definitions an alphanumeric and a file and do:
Show the lines of the file (with the numbers) which start with the alphanumeric and how many are these.
Show the lines of the file (with the numbers) that contain the alphanumeric and how many they are.
Show the lines of the file that end with the alphanumeric and how many they are

For example I have this

```
gg jj kk

gg ll mm

dd gg bb

ee zz gg
```

I want to count how many times `gg` is in the start and in the end.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no question here. What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? What is the _issue_ that you are having with this?

Comment: the question is how i can count the "gg" but the "gg" in the start only then in the end only 
eg there are 2 "gg" in the start 1 "gg" in the end

Comment: ... and by "in the start" / "in the end" you mean as first and last field of a _line_, respectively? Or how many times it occurs on the first and last line of the input file? I assume it's the former, but please edit the post to clarify.

Comment: This is a very trivial task and as such we would like to see at least some basic approach.

Comment: by the start i mean if "gg" is the first word or the last word on every line

Comment: How should a lone `gg` on a line be counted, twice? What about `ggg` at the start or end of a line? I also noticed that you dropped the "in the middle" bit between writing the title of the question and the body of the question. Should that still be part of the issue? Are fields space-separated, or do you use some other delimiter?

Comment: the middle "gg" i will count them all i need to edit the question

Comment: my only problem is how to count how many "gg" is the first word and how many is in the end

Comment: Sorry, but with your edit, you made the question even worse. Now you introduced an additional requirement: *"show the lines [...] with the numbers"*. And it sounds a lot like a school assignment. Please show your own approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-c` flag with `grep` to do this. For example, if your input file is `words`:

```
grep -c '^gg\b' words
```

will show the number of lines where `gg` appears at the start of the line.

```
grep -c '\bgg$' words
```

will show the number of lines where `gg` appears at the end of the line.

`^` and `$` are special characters that indicate the start and the end of a line, respectively.

The flag `-c` indicates you want the output to include the number of matching lines (rather than the matching lines themselves).

I've updated the answer to include `\b` which indicates a word boundary, so that it does not match words that contain `gg` as a substring.

Comment: Nice catch. I've updated the answer to include word boundaries.